# No matching function to call: error: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function in ‘f (...)’, e.g. ‘(... ->* f) (...)’

Tags: c++, function, syntax, g++

I'm trying to call a non-static member function from a thread pool. The submit function tells me error: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function in ‘f (...)’, e.g. ‘(... ->* f) (...)’ for the std::future<decltype(f(args...)) portion on the first line. I'm trying to not create a static function. I've tried a few combinations but I don't think I understand what it is asking for. Would anyone help?

```
auto submit(F&& f, Args&&... args) -> std::future<decltype(f(args...))> {
        // Create a function with bounded parameters ready to execute
        std::function<decltype(f(args...))()> func = std::bind(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        // Encapsulate it into a shared ptr in order to be able to copy construct / assign 
        auto task_ptr = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<decltype(f(args...))()>>(func);

        // Wrap packaged task into void function
        std::function<void()> wrapper_func = [task_ptr]() 
        {
            (*task_ptr)(); 
        };

        // Enqueue generic wrapper function
        m_queue.enqueue(wrapper_func);

        // Wake up one thread if its waiting
        m_conditional_lock.notify_one();

        // Return future from promise
        return task_ptr->get_future();
    }
```

[Compiler Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijtGT.png)

Update: I `changed auto submit(F&& f, Args&&... args) -> std::future<decltype(f(args...))>` to `auto submit(F&& f, Args&&... args) -> std::future<std::invoke_result_t<F, Args...>>`

Now I'm getting a new compiler error "no type named 'type'". Picture below.

[no type named 'type' compiler error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAOjO.png)

Comment: Can you include the compiler output directly in the question instead of a picture? Pictures are hard to search on a search engine.

Comment: Updated the post to include the new error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To correctly get the result type of a call to a member function or a normal function you must use `std::invoke_result_t`:

```
auto submit(F&& f, Args&&... args) -> std::future<std::invoke_result_t<F, Args...>> {
    // ...
}
```

That way, both member function and non member function will work.

Consider that when sending a member function, you must also pass the instance:

```
// object of type MyClass -----v
submit(&MyClass::member_func, my_class, param1, param2);
```

Comment: That changed something but now I'm getting the error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct std::invoke_result<int (ParallelMDFS::*)(std::shared_ptr<Tile>, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Tile> >), std::shared_ptr<Tile>&, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Tile>, std::allocator<std::shared_ptr<Tile> > >&>’